# Antd/Angular Tooltip not displayed

Tags: angular, antd

I'm new to Angular and Antd, and am trying to implement a simple tooltip on an antd icon.  The code looks right, based on the example given at https://ng.ant.design/components/tooltip/en, and while I do get the icon as expected, hovering over it does not display the tooltip.

In my app.module.ts file:

```
...
import { NgZorroAntdModule, NZ_I18N, en_US } from 'ng-zorro-antd';
import { NzToolTipModule } from 'ng-zorro-antd/tooltip';
...
import { Tooltip } from './form-elements/tooltip.component';
...
```

in my declarations array:

```
declarations: [
...
    Tooltip,
...
  ],
```

and in my imports array:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgZorroAntdModule,
...
    NzToolTipModule,
...
  ],
```

Finally, here is my tooltip.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip',
  template: `
    <span nz-tooltip nzTooltipPlacement="top" nzTooltipTitle="'ttContent'">
        <i nz-icon nzType="question-circle"></i>
    </span>
  `,
  styles: [`
    span {
        margin-left:4px;
        margin-right: 4px;
    }
  `]
})
export class Tooltip {
    @Input() ttContent:string = "Here's the tooltip content";
}
```

I'm declaring ttContent as an input so that I can pass it as a parameter in the markup of a parent component.  Other than that last bit, this is pretty much verbatim from the antd site example.

I do get the icon rendered to the screen, and if I hover over it while looking at dev tools, I see the class 'ant-tooltip-open' get applied. But no tooltip.  I assume there's something basic I'm missing, but have been poking for hours and can't see what that might be.  Anyone got some help for me?

Comment: Can you provide a Stackblitz example? With just this littlecode is difficult to say what is wrong..

Comment: https://ng-zorro-antd-start-in7msu.stackblitz.io

What's weird is that it works there, but still not in my env.  Only difference is that I removed the code to pass the tooltip content for clarity's sake, but doing that locally doesn't clear the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nzTooltipTitle` is an input for the component used by the library you are using.

For this reason, it must be rounded by square parenthesis `[nzTooltipTitle]` and without the single quote for the variable you are passing.

```
<span nz-tooltip nzTooltipPlacement="top" [nzTooltipTitle]="ttContent">
    <i nz-icon nzType="question-circle"></i>
</span>
```

In the `DefaultInput` component, you also need to remember to pass to the `Tooltip` component, the variable with the content received from the `AppComponent`.

See the [working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-zorro-antd-start-whvdgw).

Comment: Moved onto a different issue, but will test and accept answer when I return to this.  To be clear, the issue was that I didnt get a tooltip even with hardcoded data, though the information you provided is definitely helpful.  Will follow up with results - thanks for your help!